# How To Produce HTML Table of Filehashes - with Relative Path Only?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to generate a HTML table that shows a filehash (sha1) of a bunch of files in a directory; I want the filenames to be relative to my current directory - not absolute.

I know how to do all the different bits separately, but I can't figure out how to chain-them up.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
dir|get-filehash -Algorithm sha1
```

Which gives me this:

```
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA1            DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709                               C:\temp\test\empty.txt
SHA1            88A5B867C3D110207786E66523CD1E4A484DA697                               C:\temp\test\hello.txt
```

Now I only want the hash and filename , so I can do this:

```
dir|get-filehash -Algorithm sha1|select-object hash, path
```

Which gives me:

```
Hash                                                        Path
----                                                        ----
DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709                    C:\temp\test\empty.txt
88A5B867C3D110207786E66523CD1E4A484DA697                    C:\temp\test\hello.txt
```

So I can output this to an HTML file like this:

```
(dir|get-filehash -Algorithm sha1|select-object hash, path)|ConvertTo-html|add-content output.htm
```

[ignore the fact that this only works properly if the output file doesn't exist for now].

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Hash</th><th>Path</th></tr>
<tr><td>DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709</td><td>C:\temp\test\empty.txt</td></tr>
<tr><td>88A5B867C3D110207786E66523CD1E4A484DA697</td><td>C:\temp\test\hello.txt</td></tr>
</table>
```

So this gives me a HTML table; but the PATH values are absolute.

I know a simple way of getting a relative path using the 'Resolve-Path' cmdlet:

```
dir | Resolve-Path -Relative

.\empty.txt
.\hello.txt
```

But I can't get it to 'fit' in the rest of my script ; I guess their might be a .NET function to do this in a different way ? Or is there some fancy ninja-use of brackets that let me squeeze this call to a cmdlet insde of the 'select-object' list ?

I tried this: but it doesn't work:

```
# NOTE: this code does not work !
PS > dir|get-filehash|select-object hash, (path|Resolve-Path -relative)
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some progress on this - but the solution still isn't very satisfactory - since I also need control over the headers (rather than just 'name', 'value' which the HashTable provides).

I can get these headers working in a 'format-table',but still not in 'convertto-html'.

Here's the code so far:

```
function get-relative($infile) {
begin { $return_hash=@{} }
process {
    $relative_path=($_|resolve-path -Relative)
    $filehash=($_| Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha1).hash
    $return_hash.add($relative_path, $filehash)
}
end { return $return_hash }

}
```

And to call it with a formatter:

```
$table_format = @{Expression={$_.Name} ; Label="Filename"}, @{Expression={$_.Value} ; Label="CHECKSUM(SHA1)"}
dir|get-relative|format-table $table_format
```

This gives:

```
Filename                                                                CHECKSUM(SHA1)                                                         
--------                                                                --------------                                                         
.\goodbye.txt                                                           DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709                               
.\hello.txt                                                             88A5B867C3D110207786E66523CD1E4A484DA697
```

But if I shove that through a 'convertto-html', weirdness ensues. (I guess this is because the output from 'format-table' is just a string by now....)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd</th><th>pageHeaderEntry</th><th>pageFooterEntry</th><th>autosizeInfo</th><th>shapeInfo</th><th>
groupingEntry</th></tr>
<tr><td>033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo</td><
td></td></tr>
<tr><td>9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```